# Insall icedtea-8-plugin on popOS

Tags: java, icedtea

I'm trying to install icedtae-8-plugin on popOS and getting this error:

```
user@pop-os: 17:21:31 ~/Downloads/icedtea-web-1.8$ sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package icedtea-8-plugin is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java14-installer 14.0.1-1~linuxuprising1
  oracle-java11-installer-local 11.0.7-1~linuxuprising0
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'icedtea-8-plugin' has no installation candidate
```

But Java is already installed on my system:

```
haimkrupnik@pop-os: 17:25:08 ~/Downloads/icedtea-web-1.8$ java -version
java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall but no matter what I do, I can't make it work.

Comment: Applets are **dead**. Even if you managed to install the plugin, no browser will work with it. You need a time machine.

Comment: So any idea how can I open a .jnlp file?

Answer (score -1):

Try running 'javaws <.jnlp file>', that's how I load BMC applets at work.